Magento 2.3.1 Please enter a valid credit card type number error message on all credit cards
When entering a credit card, immediately after pressing the PLACE ORDER button, the screen drops down slightly and the error message "Please enter a valid credit card type number." appears under the credit card number box.  If I try another number and press Place Order, it immediately does it again like it's not even trying to contact Authorize.net to verify the card.
Authorize.net account is set up and verified to be working from Authorize.net side.
